# Window Well Cover for Boman Kemp Egress

Tags: egress

I currently have a heavy steel window well cover and frequently get frogs and other small animals falling through. I'm looking for a simple solution to attach to the metal grate to prevent debris and animals from falling in.

The plastic safety covers sell for $125; is there a plastic I can purchase and cut to shape and attach with zip ties?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: window screen .... hardware cloth ..... should the cover be transparent or opaque?

Comment: Plexiglass.....